# How can I get the sorting arrows to display for the DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, image, sorting, datatables, cdn

I've got the DataTables plugin working for my html table but, although clicking the top row causes the table to sort by the clicked-in column, the sorting arrows are not displaying.

This is how I am referencing the DataTable assets (via CDN):

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I then poke the plugin like so:

```
$('#delperfTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false
});
```

Sorting works fine, but the handy visual indicators do not display. How can I get those sort arrows to display as is, I think, supposed to be the default behavior?

I have read some info googling around about the need to "pull the images" but I want to, if possible, reference these images via CDN.

### UPDATE

Note: I also have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="bottomright">
        <h2 class="sectiontext">Delivery Performance</h2>
        <table id="delperfTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PRO*ACT Distributor</th>
                    <th>Restaurant Location</th>
                    <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Order Amount</th>
                    <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Package Count</th>
                    <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Sales</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sunrise FL</td>
                    <td>A1A ALEWORKS - #4405 - ST. AUGUSTINE</td>
                    <td class="rightjustifytext">$475.78</td>
                    <td class="rightjustifytext">28.50</td>
                    <td class="rightjustifytext">$1,903.10</td>
                </tr>
                . . . // other trs elided for brevity
                <tr class="bold">
                    <td>TOTAL</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="rightjustifytext">375.11</td>
                    <td class="rightjustifytext">23.50</td>
                    <td class="rightjustifytext">$7,966.68</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE 2

I added a couple of class, one to the table, and one to one of the columns, as follows:

```
<table id="delperfTable" class="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sorting">PRO*ACT Distributor</th>
```

...but it makes no difference.

### UPDATE 3

Here is how the table looks at runtime as it is inspected:

[image]

Comment: is bootstrap css included? do table classes match demos? No reason it shouldn't work all from cdn as long as setup and all dependencies are included

Comment: Yes, I have this:
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: and this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: The arrows get added by `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: and depends on the table having a `dataTable` class, a thead, and the cell having a `.sorting` class. What is missing in your case?

Comment: I don't see anything missing in your code wrt the demo. Inspect element and investigate further.

Comment: Could have something to do with the missing bootstrap classes on the table.

Comment: @KevinB: Each cell has to have a class="sorting"?

Comment: No, i believe that's something DataTables adds. Inspect your table and see if it is being added. ***and stop adding "UPDATE" headers to your question.*** update the existing question instead rather than leaving stale code examples around.

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html Would help you. 
Note that you should add _dataTables.bootstrap.min.css_ files after bootstrap css file. `$('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]] //Case sensitive
    } );`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is missing `rel="stylesheet"` on this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
```

This is causing the browser to silently fail to include dataTables.bootstrap.min.css  That is where the table sort up/down arrows are displayed.

In DataTables 1.10.21, dataTables.bootstrap.css (used for Bootstrap 3) contains:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  opacity: 0.5;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after {
  opacity: 0.2;
  content: "\e150";
  /* sort */
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after {
  content: "\e155";
  /* sort-by-attributes */
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
  content: "\e156";
  /* sort-by-attributes-alt */
}
```

If you are using Bootstrap 4, the file to use is dataTables.bootstrap4.css